# Find specific files containing patterns and gzip them

Tags: bash, find, gzip, seq

I have a list of log files structured like that for example : test.2020-10-17.log
I would like to gzip all the files in 2020 between January and September.
I manage to list them with find, but I would like to gzip them too.

Here the output of my current command : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AznpY.png

Comment: You say "between January and September", but your code indicates you also want October.

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three straight-forward ways to accomplish this:

1. In your example, find is unnecessary.  Just use gzip.

```
for i in $(seq -w 01 10)
do
    gzip *.2020-${i}-*.log;
done
```

If your files are buried in various levels of subdirectory, you *will* need `find`.  Then you can use

1. `find`'s `exec` capability:

```
for i in $(seq -w 01 10)
do
    find -name "*.2020-${i}-*.log" -exec gzip {} \;
done
```

3. `xargs` to call `gzip` once per batch of files instead of once per file.  It also has the ability to run multiple instances in parallel (see `-P` flag in its documentation).  If you have a large number of files:

```
for i in $(seq -w 01 10)
do
    find -name "*.2020-${i}-*.log" -print0
done | xargs -0 gzip
```

where `find`'s `-print0` flag uses ASCII 0 (NUL) to delimit printed filenames and `xargs`' `-0` flag uses ASCII 0 to delimit arguments.  That way, filenames with spaces odd characters are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"[.-]" '$3 <= "09" && $2 == "2020" {print cmd| "gzip " $0}' input_file
```